# Displaying events in full calendar using jQuery AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, fullcalendar

I am having this SQL query in `page2.php`:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE event id=?
```

In `page1.php`, I am have the calendar. How can I pass the id from page1 to page2 and display the output in page1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`events (as a function)`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/) or [`events (as a json feed)`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/) to fetch the events, and you can pass the id as a parameter in the url.

in the first case you need to add in the `data` object the `id: yourID` and in the second case like `events: "/myfeed.php?id="+yourID`

On the PHP side you will need to use the [`$_GET`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) to retrieve that id in order to use it in your query

Comment: @Alex, have you tried passing the Id as i mentioned ? do you have access to the id in `page1` and how ? javascript or php access ?

Answer (score 0):

hmm ... if you call the two pages from the browser, use `sessions` or `cookies`,

if you want to call page2 from page1 use `INCLUDE("page2.php")`. you can access variables from page1 in page2 then.

Comment: it is not applicable in FullCalender :(

Comment: i see it's JS plugin. ... include is a PHP statement not javascript. you can pass variables to JS via: var myjsvar="<?=$wellformatedPHPvar?>"; inner your js tags